# a Multi-page figure in LYX

Tags: floats

I have got a float:figure including 6 subfloat:figures in LYX. 
How can I use \ContinuedFloat command in LYX to get the figure showing onto two pages?[image]

% Preview source code

```
%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.


\usepackage{lmodern,mathpazo}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{subfig,float}

\@ifundefined{showcaptionsetup}{}{%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{caption=false}{subfig}}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\noindent \begin{centering}
\subfloat[S=0kPa]{\noindent \centering{}\includegraphics[scale=0.88]{\string"../figures/Chapter5/PDF/Al-Sharrad 2013 Anisotropic\string".pdf}}
\par\end{centering}

\noindent \begin{centering}
\subfloat[S=110kPa]{\noindent \centering{}\includegraphics[scale=0.88]{\string"../figures/Chapter5/PDF/Al-Sharrad 2013 Anisotropic\string".pdf}}
\par\end{centering}

\noindent \centering{}\caption{Bender element test results for sample prepared by anisotropic static
compaction in a triaxial cell.\label{fig:-11}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
\noindent \begin{centering}
\ContinuedFloat
\par\end{centering}

\noindent \begin{centering}
\subfloat[S=300kPa\label{fig:-11-1-1}]{\noindent \centering{}\includegraphics[scale=0.88]{\string"../figures/Chapter5/PDF/Al-Sharrad 2013 Anisotropic\string".pdf}}
\par\end{centering}

\noindent \begin{centering}
\subfloat[S=600kPa]{\noindent \centering{}\includegraphics[scale=0.88]{\string"../figures/Chapter5/PDF/Al-Sharrad 2013 Anisotropic\string".pdf}}
\par\end{centering}

\noindent \centering{}\caption{Bender element test results for sample prepared by anisotropic static
compaction in a triaxial cell.\label{fig:-11-4}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I said, please select *Complete source* (in the source pane, where it says *current paragraph*) and copy everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, i.e. the whole thing.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. sorry

Comment: Hm, your code works fine here, I get Figure 1 twice, with subfigures a,b,c,d.  I don't know if this could be the cause, but it could be that you have an older version of a package. Have you got MikTeX installed? If so, find the MikTeX Update manager (see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55473)) and use that to update your TeX system.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T.  I updated the MikTeX and solved the problem. You  were absolutely right relating the problem to update MikTeX. It is really appreciated.

Comment: Good to hear it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a second **float:figure**, and move some of the subfloats to this one. In the second figure float, insert a TeX Code box (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>) at the top and write `\ContinuedFloat` in this.

You need to load the `caption` package as well for this, so if that isn't already loaded either by LyX or yourself, go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX Preamble and add `\usepackage{caption}`.

Note that in older versions of the `caption` package there was a bug that caused the numbering of the figures to be wrong. If you experience this, update your TeX distribution.

Screenshot of appearance in LyX and PDF:

[image]

Comment: The order of the subfoats are correct, however, the order of the floats are way around.

Comment: I need on figure number for all subflaots.

Comment: Have you experienced this issue?

Comment: @AhmedM.Hasan What do you mean by the 'order of the floats are way around'? When I do what I described with just one subfigure in each figure, I get a subfigure numbered (a) in the first figure, and one numbered (b) in the second. Both figures are numbered 1 (or 1.1, depending on documentclass).

Comment: I did the same you did but still get order wrong for figures,  Figure:2 for first group of floats and Figure:1  for the second groups of floats. I could not upload a screenshot. How you do that please?

Comment: @AhmedM.Hasan Edit your question and use the button there for uploading images. Then remove the `!` just before the image. That said, a screenshot may not be that helpful. Instead, can you make the smallest document possible that demonstrates the problem (ideally just two figures with one subfigure in each), export the LaTeX code with File --> Export --> LaTeX, and add that code to the question?

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. Just have a look at the screenshot I uploaded, please.

Comment: @AhmedM.Hasan Doesn't really help for figuring out what's wrong, can you add the code as well? Either by exporting, or by opening the source pane (View --> Source pane, select *Complete source*) and copying everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AhmedM.Hasan I just remembered having seen something like this before. It could be caused by the `hyperref` package (see e.g. http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=85622&sid=7e71a6c6989f3e23e4b779e9a019c794#p85622).

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. I have added the code to my question